# Ignite DiscoveryMetricsProvider implementation?

Tags: gridgain, ignite

In our old gridgain store, we used this metrics implementation in our config:

```
<bean id="sharedFsMetricsStore" class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.metricsstore.sharedfs.GridTcpDiscoverySharedFsMetricsStore">
    <property name="path" value="${grid.metricsStorePath}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jvmMetricsStore" class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.metricsstore.vm.GridTcpDiscoveryVmMetricsStore">
</bean>
```

It appears that in ignite, the corresponding interface is DiscoveryMetricsProvider ( https://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.7.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/DiscoveryMetricsProvider.html  ). My issue is that I can't find an available implementation for this to hook into my discovery SPI. I tried looking in the source code / examples too.

What should I be using? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion about this can be found on Apache Ignite users forum: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/DiscoveryMetricsProvider-implementation-td7312.html

Comment: Thanks. To        quote the referenced discussion here for completeness : "DiscoveryMetricsProvider is a different beast and it's an internal interface implemented by DiscoveryManager. It's not intended to be provided by user. "